# Eclipse JFace's Wizards (Again ...)

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

Now that I [am able to set the content of my second wizard's page depending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954443/eclipse-jfaces-wizards) on the first page selection, I am looking for a way to give the focus to my 2nd page's content when the user clicks the next button on the first page.

By default, when the user click the next button, the focus is given to the button composite (next, back or finish button depending on the wizard configuration)

The only way I found to give focus to my page's content is the following one:

```
public class FilterWizardDialog extends WizardDialog {

    public FilterWizardDialog(Shell parentShell, IWizard newWizard) {
        super(parentShell, newWizard);
    }

    @Override
    protected void nextPressed() {
        super.nextPressed();
        getContents().setFocus();
    }
}
```

To me it's a little bit "boring and heavy" to have to override the WizardDialog class in order to implement this behavior. More over, the WizardDialog javadoc says:

> Clients may subclass `WizardDialog`, although this is rarely required.

What do you think about this solution ? Is there any easier and cleaner solution to do that job ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg14855.html) suggests:

> In your wizard page, use the inherited `setVisible()` method that is called automatically before your page is shown :

```
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
   super.setVisible(visible);
   // Set the initial field focus
   if (visible) {
      field.postSetFocusOnDialogField(getShell().getDisplay());
   }
}
```

The postSetFocusOnDialogField method contains :

```
/**
 * Posts <code>setFocus</code> to the display event queue.
 */
public void postSetFocusOnDialogField(Display display) {
    if (display != null) {
        display.asyncExec(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setFocus();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

---

Note that with [Eclipse 4.29 (Q3 2023)](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/platform_isv.php#setfocus-no-longer-activates-shell)

> ### Control.setFocus() no longer activates its Shell
>
> Previously calling Control.setFocus() also activated its
> Shell. This behavior was never documented and was never
> explained why it existed. But it caused problems: setting focus
> to a control in a background Shell caused the Shell to jump on user.
>
> Now setting focus just sets focus, even if the Shell is in the background.
> To also bring Shell to front, explicitly call `Shell.setActive()`.
>
> This change can be disabled using a Java property.
> For Example, add this VM argument in `eclipse.ini` or on
> the command line after `-vmargs:`
>
> ```
>   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.activateShellOnForceFocus=true
> ```
>
> Note: this property is only added temporarily and will be removed later.
>
> See [SWT Issue 450](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/450)

Comment: Just what I was looking for (bad googling for me ;o) )

Thanks.

Manu

Comment: @Manuel: You are welcome. I am learning about wizards thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

VonC's answer works great, I personally found it to be a little easier to work with like this though:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible) {
        Control control = getControl();
        if (!control.setFocus()) {
            postSetFocus(control);
        }
    }
}

private void postSetFocus(final Control control) {
    Display display = control.getDisplay();
    if (display != null) {
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                control.setFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```