# Little example for nested wizards in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to implement a nested wizards, for example:

wizard A -> startWizard
wizard A delegates to Wizard B or Wizard C (user input controls it)

I see on the eclipse api a class called WizardSelectionPage, that should be correct.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use it. All my wizard inherit from Wizard and implement INewWizard but for WizardSelection I need another Interface called IWizardNode?

Sorry I'm new at eclipse rcp and I don't understand at the moment all of it....

I think I have to add something into exentsion points

Thanks for help (a little small example could be nice)

I also look at -> [Eclipse JFace's Wizards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954443/eclipse-jfaces-wizards) but I could not understand what I have to do with it