# JFace wizard show data in last page

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a Wizard with 3 WizardPages, each page with widgets holding inputs from the user, I need to add a last page, holding all the informations entered by the user.

I didn't know how to do that, because the 4 pages are created at the same time.

```
Public Wizard(){
    addPage(new Page1()) ;
    addPage(new Page2()) ;
    addPage(new Page3()) ;
    addPage(new PageSummary()) ;

}
```

How can i change PageSummary Controls depending on what is entered in previous pages ?

Edit:
I've found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954542/1192335), that do exactly what i want, using the `onEnterPage()` method looks clever, here is how i have tried it:

```
public class NewEquipementSummaryPage extends WizardPage {
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    // composite to hold widgets 
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE) ;

    // composite layout 
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2, false) ;
    composite.setLayout(gl) ;

    // making widgets 
    createWidgets(composite) ;
    setControl(composite) ;
}

    public void onEnterPage() {
    TypeEquipementPage typePage = (TypeEquipementPage) getWizard().getPage(TypeEquipementPage.PAGE_NAME) ;
    CompanySellerPage companyPage = (CompanySellerPage) getWizard().getPage(CompanySellerPage.PAGE_NAME) ;
    EquipementUserPage userPage = (EquipementUserPage) getWizard().getPage(EquipementUserPage.PAGE_NAME) ;

    if(typePage.types[0].getSelection() == true)
        typeEquipementLabel.setText("Poste de travail") ;
    else
        typeEquipementLabel.setText("Peripherique") ;

    marqueEquipementLabel.setText(typePage.marquesCombo.getText()) ;
    descriptionEquipementLabel.setText(typePage.descriptionField.getText()) ;

    if(companyPage.companyExistButton[0].getSelection() == true) {
        companyNameLabel.setText(companyPage.companiesCombo.getText()) ;
    }
    else{
        companyNameLabel.setText(companyPage.companyNameField.getText()) ;
        companyAdressLabel.setText(companyPage.companyAdressField.getText()) ;
        companyNumberLabel.setText(companyPage.companyNumberField.getText()) ;
    }

    if( !(userPage.sharedEquipementButton.getSelection()) )
        useOfEquipementLabel.setText("Utilisateur") ;
    else
        useOfEquipementLabel.setText("Bureau") ;

    pack() ;
}
```

With the pack() method in the end, i have an error in compilation (cannot find symbol)

and without it nothing appear in the page .. what did I miss ?

Comment: The `onEnterPage` method as used in that link is just a custom method to handle entering the page in the 'Creating JFace Wizards' tutorial. It's called from their Wizard when it calls their overridden `Wizard#getNextPage`. Nothing will call it automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding `DialogPage#setVisible` in `NewEquipementSummaryPage` and call `onEnterPage` from there:

```
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {

    super.setVisible(visible);

    if (visible) {

        onEnterPage();
    }
}
```

(as well as changing to `composite.pack()` as suggested in SoboLAN's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `composite.pack ()`, not just `pack ()`. To do this, store the `composite` variable as a `private` field in your class (so that you can have acess to it in the `onEnterPage` method).

Comment: it's composite.pack() .. and it didn't work

is there another way to do what I'm plaining ?
the last page in the wizard serve as a summary to what do user has entered in all previous pages, so he can read and change by pressing previous and update values or validate by pressing finish.

i made empty labels where informations will be displayed using the setText() method in the onEnterPage() ..

Comment: I used a log to see if there is a call for the onEnterPage() method, but only the createControl() method is called during the process ..

When i verified the javadoc there is no onEnterPage() method in the IWizardPage interface not even an inerhited one ..

Where is this method ?

Comment: @elaich I found that method here: http://www.eclipse.org/epf/composer_javadoc/1.0/org/eclipse/epf/library/ui/wizards/BaseWizardPage.html . However I don't know what its purpose is...

Comment: The `onEnterPage` method in the link in the OP's question is just a custom method to handle entering the page in the 'Creating JFace Wizards' tutorial. It's called from their Wizard when it calls their overridden `Wizard#getNextPage`. Nothing will call it automatically